# Recommend a good DAL for a Python/Tornado app

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, data-access-layer, tornado

I've been googling for hours and it just failed me.

Are there any DAL/ORMs that support mysql/google app engine besides the one in web2py?

I'm working on a tornado webapp and I need the abstraction badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django with [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) for AppEngine support.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , you cannot use a relation database inside GAE, (although you can use a webservice to do the same), there is no way to achieve the same directly.

> Django-nonrel is an independent
>   branch of Django that adds NoSQL
>   database support to the ORM. The
>   long-term goal is to add NoSQL support
>   to the official Django release.

Comment: The OP is asking about a library that lets him transparently use the App Engine datastore or an SQL database, not a library that lets him use an SQL database on App Engine.